# Links not working on first click on oscommerce

Tags: html, oscommerce

There is an oscommerce site that I maintain now. There are some links on the homepage like below when one visits the site first time.

```
http://website.com/index.php?cPath=2?osCsid=80b28bcd9ad38e38e7ded7e200f87b30
```

This click leads to **Not Found** error:

The requested URL /the-carriers-c-2 was not found on this server.

But if I go back on homepage and click then this link works without any problem.

On 2nd visit the URLs change to : `http://website.com/the-carriers-c-2.html`

This seems to be a very peculiar problem, I am new to oscommerce so not sure what the reason is.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have an SEO URLs module installed that was not set up properly

Comment: I am unable to find out any such module.

Comment: `catalog/includes/functions/html_output.php` and seo.class.php will be modified/on your site if you do

Answer (score 1):

What version of oscommerce are you running.

earlier versions of oscommerce required third party mods for SEO URLs. I agree with random, that is a generated url by the system.

you should have an .htaccess file in your root, it may be renaned or missing, also you need to have MOD URL REWRITE running on your apache web server so apache knows to handle these kinds of urls properly.